# extracting unique rows from dataframe in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to trim the dataframe or create a new one so it has only unique rows considering certain columns. Now I have:

```
time_original time_seconds time_round time_below time_above
273.0         21.782       22.0        0.0       52.0
273.0         21.816       22.0        0.0       52.0
273.0         21.849       22.0        0.0       52.0
273.0         21.882       22.0        0.0       52.0
273.0         104.143      104.0       74.0      134.0
273.0         104.176      104.0       74.0      134.0
273.0         104.210      104.0       74.0      134.0
```

and I would like to take into consideration the last 3 columns to print only unique rows. So to have:

```
time_round time_below time_above
22.0       0.0        52.0
104.0      74.0       134.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) for select last 3 columns with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.iloc[:, -3:].drop_duplicates()
print (df)
   time_round  time_below  time_above
0        22.0         0.0        52.0
4       104.0        74.0       134.0
```

Comment: And if I wanted to calculate the mean from the time_seconds column for the respective intervals? i.e the mean for 0 to 52 would be the mean of the first 4 rows in the time_seconds column and the mean for 74 to 134 would be the mean of corresponding rows in this column? Thanks

Comment: update. I used df.groupby('time_below', as_index=False)[time_seconds].mean() and it worked.